# Update users details without a password by admin. Rails 3.x Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I would like to create a link to approve a users signup,

1) First solution

```
<%= link_to "Approve", edit_user_registration_path(:id => user.id, :approved => true), :method => :put  %>
```

However it drops back `No route matches [PUT] "/users/edit"`

2) Also I was thinking about an extra action that will respond to a specific route and update the user signup, say

```
match '/users/approve_user', :controller => 'users', :action => 'approve_user', :collection => { :my_action => :put}
```

and in the view:

```
%- link_to "Approve", users_approve_user_path(:id => user.id), :method => :put
```

However, it gives back that `Couldn't find User with ID=approve_user`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Always try to check each gem's github wiki page. So here is devise's wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages. And here is what you are looking for: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use custom routing with devise

This is direct from devise documentation (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), *configuring routes*

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

so in your case try something like

```
devise_scope :user do
  post "Approve", :to => "users/approve_user"
end
```

and please note, by default device users controller comes under the name space 'devise'.